# High consumption of gas puzzle

Tags: gas-limit

Normal transfer works normally with this erc20 token: https://etherscan.io/address/0xe9e74bae31892b6b1c000e009c93438dbd14d723#code
When withdrawing from the Etherdelta contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819, it uses too much gas and the transaction fails. Looking at the geth trace it does this when it gets to SSTORE. Example transaction where this happens: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x86f1bb1cdd200723662026b59db4dbd91cf24a5a7a785574d3ae4188baeb14ae
This contract has a mint function and it seems before that was used withdrawing from Etherdelta worked normally: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0e2705298acf45f36cc74a56f881280d49c40e0917fd2c5872f52998985cb446

Can anyone explain what is happening?

There is a similar contract that does not have this problem: https://etherscan.io/address/0xee609fe292128cad03b786dbb9bc2634ccdbe7fc#code

Comment: What parameters did you use when you called withdrawToken?

Comment: Those are determined by the Etherdelta smart contract. Max gas limit is set to 250000, but with a normal transfer that would be more than enough.  What is strange is there is an almost identical contract that is able to withdraw from Etherdelta, and withdrawToken worked fine before.

Comment: My guess is the line `if(transferIns[msg.sender].length > 0) delete transferIns[msg.sender];` is clearing the storage and it is causing the call to use too much gas. You have to contact the contract authors to advice on what you can do.

Comment: And yet this contract:  https://etherscan.io/address/0xee609fe292128cad03b786dbb9bc2634ccdbe7fc#code is exactly the same if(transferIns[msg.sender].length > 0) delete transferIns[msg.sender]; and doesn't have the same withdraw problem.

Comment: @Curious2424 `transferIns[msg.sender]` is an array, and delete is trying to release the storage, if the array is large it will spend a large amount of gas because it has to set all elements to zero. Different contracts can have different storages and will have different expenditures.